# How to take Elasticsearch single index backup

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

Can someone guide me to take single index backup in elasticsearch. When I search for this, I get all commands to take full snapshot.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a snapshot of all open and started indices in the cluster is created. This behavior can be changed by specifying the list of indices in the body of the snapshot request.

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_2?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "index_1,index_2",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```